# Making first column of table sticky

Tags: html, css

I need to get my first column to stay as sticky when I scroll table side ways.

https://jsfiddle.net/zinoui/BmLpV/

Already tried this but couldn't get it work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
td {
border-spacing: 1;
border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;

}
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 15;
width: 100%;
}

td {
text-align: left;
padding: 8px;
color: black;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;

}
th.rotate {
height: 140px;
white-space: nowrap;
}

th.rotate > div {
transform:
translate(47px,50px)
rotate(315deg);
width: 30px;
}
th.rotate > div > span {
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
padding: 5px 10px;
}
.csstransforms & th.rotate {
height: 140px;
white-space: nowrap;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
<table>
<tr>
<th>Nimi</th>
<th class="rotate"><div><span>Testitestitesti</span></div></th>
<th class="rotate"><div><span>Testitestitesti</span></div></th>
<th class="rotate"><div><span>Testitestitesti</span></div></th>
<th class="rotate"><div><span>Testitestitesti</span></div></th>
<th class="rotate"><div><span>Testitestitesti</span></div></th>
<th class="rotate"><div><span>Testitestitesti</span></div></th>
<th class="rotate"><div><span>Testitestitesti</span></div></th>
<th class="rotate"><div><span>Testitestitesti</span></div></th>
<th class="rotate"><div><span>Testitestitesti</span></div></th>
<th class="rotate"><div><span>Testitestitesti</span></div></th>
<th class="rotate"><div><span>Testitestitesti</span></div></th>
<th class="rotate"><div><span>Testitestitesti</span></div></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<a href="#1" style="color:black">
<div style="height:100%;width:100%">
Pelle<br>Pyrkyri
</div></a></td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<a href="#2" style="color:black">
<div style="height:100%;width:100%">

Lilli<br>Lyllerö
</div></a></td>
<td bgcolor="red"></td>
<td bgcolor="red"></td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
<td bgcolor="red"></td>
<td bgcolor="red"></td>
<td bgcolor="red"></td>

<td bgcolor="red"></td>
<td bgcolor="red"></td>
<td bgcolor="red"></td>
<td bgcolor="red"></td>
<td bgcolor="red"></td>
<td bgcolor="red"></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>Kelpo<br>Keppana</td>
<td bgcolor="red"></td>
<td bgcolor="red"></td>
<td bgcolor="red"></td>
<td bgcolor="red"></td>
<td bgcolor="red"></td>
<td bgcolor="red"></td>
<td bgcolor="red"></td>
<td bgcolor="red"></td>
<td bgcolor="red"></td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Paula<br>Pauligilta</td>
<td bgcolor="red"></td>
<td bgcolor="red"></td>
<td bgcolor="red"></td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
<td bgcolor="red"></td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
<td bgcolor="red"></td>
<td bgcolor="red"></td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
<td bgcolor="red"></td>
<td bgcolor="red"></td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Alfred<br>Aikuinen</td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
<td bgcolor="##006600"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is what I tried with solution found here: https://jsfiddle.net/zinoui/BmLpV/ . First column stayed sticky but everything else is screwed and not working as intended. Here is my try: https://jsfiddle.net/vzwpyjke/

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not use `position:sticky` instead `absolute`, https://jsfiddle.net/mxr2Lhnf/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the column a `position: absolute`

Check out this example, should have what you need:

HTML

```
<div class="zui-wrapper">
    <div class="zui-scroller">
        <table class="zui-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="zui-sticky-col">Name</th>
                    <th>Number</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Height</th>
                    <th>Born</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                    <th>Prior to NBA/Country</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col">DeMarcus Cousins</td>
                    <td>15</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                    <td>6'11"</td>
                    <td>08-13-1990</td>
                    <td>$4,917,000</td>
                    <td>Kentucky/USA</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col">Isaiah Thomas</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>PG</td>
                    <td>5'9"</td>
                    <td>02-07-1989</td>
                    <td>$473,604</td>
                    <td>Washington/USA</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col">Ben McLemore</td>
                    <td>16</td>
                    <td>SG</td>
                    <td>6'5"</td>
                    <td>02-11-1993</td>
                    <td>$2,895,960</td>
                    <td>Kansas/USA</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col">Marcus Thornton</td>
                    <td>23</td>
                    <td>SG</td>
                    <td>6'4"</td>
                    <td>05-05-1987</td>
                    <td>$7,000,000</td>
                    <td>Louisiana State/USA</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col">Jason Thompson</td>
                    <td>34</td>
                    <td>PF</td>
                    <td>6'11"</td>
                    <td>06-21-1986</td>
                    <td>$3,001,000</td>
                    <td>Rider/USA</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.zui-table {
    border: none;
    border-right: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}
.zui-table thead th {
    background-color: #DDEFEF;
    border: none;
    color: #336B6B;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.zui-table tbody td {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
    color: #333;
    padding: 10px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.zui-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.zui-scroller {
    margin-left: 141px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: visible;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 300px;
}
.zui-table .zui-sticky-col {
    border-left: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
    border-right: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    width: 120px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zinoui/BmLpV/

Comment: As I stated after code I tried t hat but didn't manage to get it work properly. Here is my result again with that:  https://jsfiddle.net/vzwpyjke/

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.

It's weird to use a `<br />` tag within the `<td>`

How about adding a static height to your `<td>` css:

```      
td {
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        height:40px;

      }
```